# How to check, whether a char is visible in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascii

I'm processing `keyup` events and would like to know, whether `e.which` links to a visible symbol - e.g. UP key (38) isn't visible, "a" is. Of course it's just possible to create a list of symbol codes of each type, but I was wondering, whether an easier way exists for JS / JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you detect keycodes from 48 to 90 you will detect the visible chars, then the next codes like multiply, decimal point and so on with codes: 106-111.

Another keycodes with "visibles" characters are from 186-192 and 219-222.

So, the visible chars will be 48-90, 106-111, 186-192 and 219-222. The rest no.

More info in this [link](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

You will try your visible chars, also, with this [link](http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html).

Comment: There are plenty of other visible ranges such as 32 - 47 which are character symbols.

Comment: @Matthew Cox, I can guarantee, that UP key has code 38, and it's not visible. Are you examining the different list?

Comment: I am simply looking at an ASCII table. 38 for example, is an ampersand (&)

Comment: Between 32 and 47 there are the arrow keys also.

Comment: @Matthew Cox, looks like these codes are different from the ASCII, the link Galled has given contains the actual codes.

Comment: @Fluffy Ahhh I see. Well then, you are just going to have to build range checks =P